# How to create and save an excel file to a specific location in a java application?

Tags: java

I want to create an excel file using `addHeader` and save it in a desired location on my system. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

At present, my file is created and saved, but its getting saved in the downloads folder.

**(Update from comments)**

This is part of my code:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\\Report.xls\"");    
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel")
```

Comment: This is very vague ... are you using apache-poi? Other libs? ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What code isn't working for you now? (What have you tried so far?)

Comment: Please read the FAQ before submitting questions. You do not provide any details. What do you mean by 'addHeader', is this a web application, which framework do you use, what did you try, etc.?

Comment: In. NET you can specify the directory in the save dialog. But I'm not sure Java.

Answer (score -1):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) allows java applications to manage Microsoft documents.

Comment: This is the part of my code-                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\\Report.xls\"");
  response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel")